# Canada Express Entry - Date you first became qualified to practice in this occupation

Tags: resident-permit, canada, canadian-citizens, express-entry

I am applying for Express Entry in Canada as a Software Engineer (NOC 2173). In the website it says that this occupation **usually** requires a university degree. I am ok with that, I got my degree, but I have work experience (outside Canada) since two years before I got my degree. Also, a university degree is not required legally for practicing software development. Many people who are great software developers never went to university.

My question is, should I put my graduation date as the date I first became qualified to practice this occupation? Or should I put the date I started my first job as a software engineer?

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you are not applying in a stream where this information is relevant (e.g. skilled trade program) and your degree is not too recent to disqualify you (e.g. less than a year ago). If you are worried, put the information in a letter of explanation.